# How can I eliminate duplicate Date headers when using Jetty and Apache CXF?

Tags: http-headers, jetty, cxf, embedded-jetty

I am working on a legacy application which runs as an embedded Jetty server. The very first code that is called is:

```
Server server = new Server();
server.setSendDateHeader(true);
```

Next some contexts are created to bind specific servlets at /, /app and /api.

The Servlet bound to /api extends AbstractCXFServlet and is used to return responses to the RESTful API. However, what I have found is calls to /api have duplicate Date: headers in the response. The servlets at the other endpoints are not CXF based. The [Date: header is required](http://pretty-rfc.herokuapp.com/RFC2616#header.date)  so removing the `server.setSendDateHeader(true)` or setting it to false won't work since all the requests to / and /app would then have it missing.

Is there a way to configure Jetty to only add the Date header if it doesn't exist at the end of processing or is there a way to disable CXF from inserting Date: headers?

I'm using Jetty v6.1.19 and CXF v2.3.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems CXF must use the addHeader instead of setHeader which would replace the value which Jetty has already inserted.

In the end I had to write a ServletFilter and ResponseWrapper which is only used on the /api Context. [This thread](http://www.apacheserver.net/Duplicate-Headers-at1321236.htm) ended up sending me down this route.

**DateHeaderStrippingFilter.java**

```
public class DateHeaderStrippingFilter
    implements Filter
{
    private HashSet<String> headers;

    @Override
    public void destroy()
    {
        headers = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        HeaderStripperWrapper wrappedResponse = new HeaderStripperWrapper((HttpServletResponse)response, headers);   
        chain.doFilter(request, wrappedResponse);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig config)
        throws ServletException
    {
        headers = new HashSet<String>();
        headers.add("Date");
    }
}
```

**HeaderStripperWrapper.java**

```
public class HeaderStripperWrapper
    extends HttpServletResponseWrapper
{
    private HashSet<String> headersToStrip;

    public HeaderStripperWrapper(HttpServletResponse response, HashSet<String> headersToStrip)
    {
        super(response);
        this.headersToStrip = headersToStrip;
    }

    @Override  
    public void addHeader(String name, String value)  
    {  
        if (!headersToStrip.contains(name))
        {
            super.addHeader(name, value);
        }
    }  

    @Override  
    public void setHeader(String name, String value)  
    {  
        if (!headersToStrip.contains(name))
        {
            super.setHeader(name, value);
        }
    }
}
```

and then when configuring the embedded jetty server

```
Context api = new Context(contexts, "/api", false, false);
BooksApiServlet apiServlet = env.getInjector().getInstance(ApiServlet.class);   
ServletHolder holder = new ServletHolder(apiServlet);
api.addServlet(holder, "/*");
api.addFilter(DateHeaderStrippingFilter.class, "/*", 0);
```